# Я чего-то не понимаю в mockk-тестах

Tags: android, kotlin, юнит-тесты

Хочу покрыть свою небольшую программу тестами. Поизучал фреймворк **mockk**, посмотрел множество видео на ютубе, прочитал статей как русскоязычных, так и на английском языке. И почти во всех видео, примеры с тестами на интерфейсах которое возвращают значения которое в них передают.

А теперь к сути:

```
fun searchExceptionNumber(word: String, exclusionsTexts: String){

        val exceptions = exclusionsTexts
        var keyExclusionsValues: Int = 0

         for(index in word){
             for (char in exceptions){
                 if (index == char){
                     dataStore.exclusionsValues.put(keyExclusionsValues, char)
                 }
             }
             keyExclusionsValues++
         }
    }
```

Функция получает два string-значения. Она проверяет **word** и **exclusionsTexts** и совпадающие элементы и номера этих значений в **hashmap** (**exclusionsValues**, это **hashmap**).

Пример:

```
ввод: word = "thanks", exclusionsTexts = "ak"
итог: exclusionsValues = ['a'-> 2], ['k'-> 4]
```

Так вот, как мне написать unit-тест для проверки этого.

Comment: Для тестирования этой функции моки не нужны. В тесте вызывайте функцию и проверяйте, что оно вернула то, что должна.

Comment: Мокать надо внешние зависимости, недоступные в тестовом окружении. У вашей функции внешняя зависимость одна -> `dataStore`.